# python jump to a line in a txt file (a gzipped one)

Tags: python, file-io

I'm reading through a large file, and processing it.
I want to be able to jump to the middle of the file without it taking a long time.

right now I am doing:

```
f = gzip.open(input_name)
for i in range(1000000):
    f.read() # just skipping the first 1M rows

for line in f:
    do_something(line)
```

is there a faster way to skip the lines in the zipped file?
If I have to unzip it first, I'll do that, but there has to be a way.

It's of course a text file, with `\n` separating lines.

Comment: You should consider a different storage format for your needs. What are your needs?

Comment: How many bytes per line?

Answer (score 11):

The nature of gzipping is such that there is no longer the concept of lines when the file is compressed -- it's just a binary blob. Check out [this](http://www.gzip.org/deflate.html) for an explanation of what gzip does.

To read the file, you'll need to decompress it -- the `gzip` module does a fine job of it. Like other answers, I'd also recommend `itertools` to do the jumping, as it will carefully make sure you don't pull things into memory, and it will get you there as fast as possible.

```
with gzip.open(filename) as f:
    # jumps to `initial_row`
    for line in itertools.slice(f, initial_row, None):
        # have a party
```

Alternatively, if this is a CSV that you're going to be working with, you could also try clocking `pandas` parsing, as it can handle decompressing `gzip`. That would look like: `parsed_csv = pd.read_csv(filename, compression='gzip')`.

Also, to be extra clear, when you iterate over file objects in python -- i.e. like the `f` variable above -- you iterate over lines. You do not need to think about the '\n' characters.

Comment: I acknowledged you mentioned itertools @PadraicCunningham, I'm not competing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I was trying to explain things in a useful manner. If you disagree, you're welcome to down vote me. That's all I'm going to say.

Comment: Why not add a pandas example? That would be useful.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, happily.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), passing a file object `f` and  starting point, it will still advance the iterator but more efficiently than calling next 1000000 times:

```
from itertools import islice

for line in islice(f,1000000,None):
     print(line)
```

Not overly familiar with gzip but I imagine `f.read()` reads the whole file so the next 999999 calls are doing nothing. If you wanted to manually advance the iterator you would call next on the file object i.e `next(f)`.

Calling `next(f)` won't mean all the lines are read into memory at once either, it advances the iterator one line at a time so if you want to skip a line or two in a file or a header it can be useful.

The [consume](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)  recipe as @wwii suggested recipe is also worth checking out

Comment: Maybe use the ```consume``` function from the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and pass it ```iter(file object)```.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

If you know the number of bytes you want to skip, you can use `.seek(amount)` on the file object, but in order to skip a number of lines, Python has to go through the file byte by byte to count the newline characters.

The only alternative that comes to my mind is if you handle a certain static file, that won't change. In that case, you can index it once, i.e. find out and remember the positions of each line. If you have that in e.g. a dictionary that you save and load with `pickle`, you can skip to it in quasi-constant time with `seek`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to randomly seek within a gzip file. Gzip is a stream algorithm and so it must always be uncompressed from the start until where your data of interest lies.

It is not possible to jump to a specific line without an index. Lines can be scanned forward or scanned backwards from the end of the file in continuing chunks.

You should consider a different storage format for your needs. What are your needs?